# What time does ls -l return

Tags: unix

What time does the ls -l give ? - Is it the mtime or the atime.

ctime

ctime is the inode or file change time. The ctime gets updated when the file attributes are changed, like changing the owner, changing the permission or moving the file to an other filesystem but will also be updated when you modify a file.

mtime

mtime is the file modify time. The mtime gets updated when you modify a file. Whenever you update content of a file or save a file the mtime gets updated.

Most of the times ctime and mtime will be the same, unless only the file attributes are updated. In that case only the ctime gets updated.

atime

atime is the file access time. The atime gets updated when you open a file but also when a file is used for other operations like grep, sort, cat, head, tail and so on.

Comment: By default, `ls -l` shows the modification time; `ls -lu` shows you the access time (option `-a` is used to list all the files, so the mnemonic is 'use' time), and `ls -lc` shows you the change time. On Mac OS X, there's also a creation time (birth time), listed with `ls -lU`. Using `man ls` would reveal all of this (or all the parts relevant to your system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows the modification time. You can verify this by using `touch -m` to manipulate the modification time on a file and observing the results with `ls -l`.

Comment: Isnt the touch command also modifies the atime ?

Comment: You just have to read the file for this (the atime), so just use `cat`  or `head` or something.

Comment: @Angus Hence the `-m` flag, which tells it to only change the modification time (see the man page).